# Group Chat in Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, websocket, django-channels

I am tring to create group chat in Django with Channels. Here below you can see my code. After submit the message nothing happens. Also Log in empty. How to make code work?

**routing.py**:

```
channel_routing = [
    route('websocket.connect', ws_connect, path=r'^account/dashboard/projects/(?P<project_code>[0-9a-f-]+)/chat/$'),
    route("websocket.receive", ws_receive),
    route("websocket.disconnect", ws_disconnect),
]
```

**consumers.py**:

```
# Connected to websocket.connect
@channel_session
def ws_connect(message):
    query = parse.parse_qs(message['query_string'])
    if 'username' not in query:
        return
    room = message.content['path'].strip("/")
    Group('chat-%s' % room).add(message.reply_channel)
    message.channel_session['room'] = room
    message.channel_session['username'] = query['username'][0]
    message.reply_channel.send({"accept": True})


# Connected to websocket.receive
@channel_session
def ws_receive(message):
    if 'username' not in message.channel_session:
        return
    Group('chat-%s' % message.channel_session['room']).send({
        'text': json.dumps({
            'message': message.content['text'],
            'username': message.channel_session['username']
        })
    })


# Connected to websocket.disconnect
@channel_session
def ws_disconnect(message):
    Group("chat-%s" % message.channel_session['room']).discard(message.reply_channel)
```

**template**:

```
{% block content %}
    <h1>{{ room.code }}</h1>
    <div id="msgArea"></div>

    <div>
        <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    </div>

    <button id="btnSubmit">Submit</button>
{% endblock content %}

{% block script %}
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var msgArea = $('#msgArea')
            var elementMessage = $('#message')
            var webSocket = new WebSocket('ws://' + window.location.host + '/account/dashboard/projects/(?P<{{ room.project_id }}>[0-9a-f-]+)/chat/');
            webSocket.onmessage = function(message) {
                var data = JSON.parse(message.data)
                msgArea.append('<p><strong>'+ data.username + '</strong>: ' + data.message + '</p>')
            }
            $('#btnSubmit').click(function(e) {
                webSocket.send(elementMessage.val())
            })
        })
    </script>
{% endblock script %}
```

Comment: Are you running the Django server and the Channels server?

Comment: @Tom sure, both servers run. I see the page. Redis server say websocker connected but when I send message nothing happens. Do you have any ideas about that?